# How to use ndk-gdb debug executable ELF without AndroidManifest.xml on android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb

I used cmake & ndk build below hello.cpp and run it on android.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Follow the gdb instruction. run `gdbserver :1234 hello` on android device.
When run `$NDK/ndk-gdb` on macOS encounter error msg `ERROR: Could not find AndroidManifest.xml in current directory or a parent directory. Launch this script from inside a project, or use --project=<path>.`

How to debug native c++ project without AndroidManifest.xml on android platform?